# Unresolved external symbol _BCryptEnumRegisteredProviders@8 when using CNG on Windows 10

Tags: windows, linker-errors, cng

I'm trying to do my first step with CNG (Cryptography Next Generation) in VC++ 2015 (Windows 10 x64). Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    ULONG cbBufSize = 0;
    PCRYPT_PROVIDERS pBuf = NULL;
    status = BCryptEnumRegisteredProviders(&cbBufSize, &pBuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Building the project (for x86), I got an error message:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
>   _BCryptEnumRegisteredProviders@8 referenced in function _main

I then tried to install "CNG Software Development Kit" and configured the project following this instruction: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18713/Simple-way-to-crypt-a-file-with-CNG
but project building gave the same error message.

Please help!

PS: I did the same thing in (Win7 x86, VS 2008) and it worked without any error.

Comment: Did you indeed add `bcrypt.lib` to the linker's Additional dependencies, and does this file exist?

Comment: @GSerg: Well, I forgot about the library file. I now added the file and the project was built without any error. Thank you!

Comment: But when I switched building mode from **Debug** to **Release**, the error appeared again. And when I copied the EXE-file (the result of building in **Debug** mode) to a Windows 7 x86 machine and tried to run it, I got error message "The program can't start because VCRUNTIME140D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem". Please help again, especially @GSerg.

Comment: Did you add `bcrypt.lib` for all build configurations, or just for Debug?

Comment: Oh my god!!!!! How silly I am! Yes, I added the 'bcrypt.lib' just for **Debug** build configuration. The problem is now resolved! Thanks again, @GSerg!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)